# How to avoid nesting method calls?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a `Question` object. Each `Question` holds instances of follow-up questions, which should be displayed afterwards. During question display a `string` param is passed.

If I have `Question`'s: Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, the Q1 might contain following data:

```
Q1:
    questions: {
        "abc": Q2,
        "def": Q3,
        "xyz": Q2
    }
```

When `"abc"` is selected, Q2 instance is passed `"abc"` string and is displayed.

The way I have it implemented:

```
class Question {
     public void Show(string option){
         // ... display
         var selectedOption = GetSelected();
         // questions["abc"] = Q2
         questions[selectedOption].Show(selectedOption);
}
```

I instantly got that feeling that I made a very wrong turn somewhere. It won't happen, but with big enough number of questions I'd overflow the call stack. And even in real-world scenario it's going to make stack traces horrible and unreadable.

I thought of changing it to:

```
class Question {
     public Question Show(string option){
         // ... display
         var selectedOption = GetSelected();
         // questions["abc"] = Q2
         var next = questions[selectedOption];
         next.SetValue(selectedOption);
         return next;
}
```

and call it from outside, one by one. But I'm afraid that the whole idea is flawed, so my question: is my modified idea at least semi-decent, or is there a better way of achieving this kind of user-input based linked-objects execution?

Comment: Actually, your first logic looks ok, as long as you have some terminating condition. As per my understanding, you need to check the questions collection before making the recursive call.

Comment: Terminating question doesn't have any further questions and in actual code there is a check for that :) But of course, a valid point.

Comment: Data format seems wrong to me. Question don't need to contain links to another questions, instead you could have `List<Question>` to define *order*. All questions can then find themselves in that list to get *next* question.

Comment: I think I was not explicit enough while describing the data structure - each question has a set of next questions, not just single one, and which one is chosen is based on user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now I went with following:

```
class Question {
 private Dictionary<string, Question> questions = ...
 public Question Show(){
     // ... display
     var selectedOption = GetSelected();
     // questions["abc"] = Q2
     var next = questions[selectedOption];

     if(next != null)
         next.SetValue(selectedOption);

     return next;
}
```

and then

```
{ \\ in some method
  Question q = Q1;
  do{
    q = q.Show();
  } while( q != null)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd split the generation of the question chain from displaying questions. Generating the chain could look like this:

```
for (Question q = initialQuestion; q.Next != null; q = q.Next)
 yield return q;
```

And "showing" them:

```
foreach (var q in GetQuestionChain(initialQuestion))
 q.Show(); //No recursion.
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think that his approach doesn't take into consideration the tree-like structure - q.Next is a list :)

Comment: OK, recursion becomes more attractive, then. I won't be writing this up but the same idea of splitting the enumeration from processing still applies.